# PHP To Monitor Server Statistics

Tags: php, monitoring, health-monitoring, network-monitoring

Is there a way with PHP to get statistics about external servers such as:

- Download/Upload speed
- Up-time
- Online/Offline

If not with PHP any other web language?

I would like to have a subdomain servers.domain.com which has login authentication where it will list all servers (about 10) and have the statistics above shown. They are not all on the same network, about 3 are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want either a monitoring package like Nagios, or a statistics tracking tool like Cacti, or both.